# rake gems:install throws error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rake

I am trying to install `queue-tip` on my asterisk server using the following guide:
http://queue-tip.rubyforge.org/install.html

However I am unable to proceed past the following step as it throws this error:

*rake gems:install
rake aborted!
undefined method `name' for "abstract":String
Tasks: TOP => environment*

Any help please?

Answer (score 2):

To install a gem, use the `gem` command, e.g. `gem install rails`.   If you're in a Rails 3.x environment, add to the file `Gemfile.rb` in a format similar to others already included, then run `bundle install` from your project directory.